# py.test main() invocation examples

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have this structure.

```
 /bin 
   __init__.py
   run_test.py (call pytest.main)
 /tests
   __init__.py
   test_xyz.py
```

If I call run_test.py using simply via pytest.main(), it won't invoke tests in "tests" module. I tried passing couple of parameters like module="tests" etc but they don't work. I have to altogether chuck auto discovery and use the suite parameter for it to pick up any tests.

What am I missing? I tried to walk through the code in the pytest module, but it is way too complex to understand. And the documentation is very bad.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the full path of what to execute.

```
import pytest

pytest_args = [
    '/tests',
    # other tests here...
]
pytest.main(pytest_args)
```

This will execute all the tests found in the directory,
there is no need to have `/tests/__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's later answer.
I hope it could help somebody in the future.

It's better to have `run_test.py` in root project dir, I mean you would move out `run_test.py` from `/bin` to one higher level project structure.